# kuberctl not work with remote cluster on windows

Tags: kubernetes

I want to control my remote k8s cluster but have a problem with it

I have kubeconfig file from k8s cluster admin. But when I try to connect cluster I take a mistake, when get with browser - result is ok

```
kubectl version --kubeconfig ./.kube/config -v=12 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --alsologtostderr
I0211 18:13:42.625408   12960 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file ./.kube/config

...

I0211 18:13:54.691273   12960 helpers.go:216] Connection error: Get https://k8s-t-deponl-01.raiffeisen.ru:8443/version?timeout=32s: Tunnel Connection Failed
F0211 18:13:54.692219   12960 helpers.go:116] Unable to connect to the server: Tunnel Connection Failed
```

With browser take answer:

```
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "11",
  "gitVersion": "v1.11.5",
  "gitCommit": "753b2dbc622f5cc417845f0ff8a77f539a4213ea",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2018-11-26T14:31:35Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.10.3",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
```

Why I have that problem?

Comment: can you provide more information about your set up? Is there any proxy  involved?

Comment: yes i have corporate proxy, but I setup http_proxy and https_proxy variables